# How to debug "Unexpected token '.'" in React-Native / Metro?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, metro-bundler

I have a working React-Native project, without any error.

I run it using `npm run android` that execute `react-native run-android`.

When I add a particular (it's only that particular package that generate this error)

`import custom-lib from '@company/custom-lib'`

I have the following screen (using `react-native` and `metro`) :

[image: Stacktrace]

I'm not asking how to solve this issue, because it's in-house devloppment.

However, I have too few stacktrace, I cannot debug it.

Is it possible to know, were in my code / library the problem occurs ? or is it elsewhere ? (This library is also imported in other projects, and is working fine)

Comment: If you can, maybe try to launch the chrome debbuger, or running with --stacktrace... You should be able to get more infos (There s maybe others ways I guess)

Comment: I run the app, using `npm run android`. If I switch the scripts to be `react-native run-android --stacktrace` I get a `error: unknown option `--stacktrace'` error.

Comment: Do not hesitate to put some console log to find the crash point, print just a char till you find the line, and then print the differents variables to find the bug, maybe not the best way but it works

Comment: how ? I don't have any stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to get much more information in my stacktrace using the following step:

1. Execute `adb shell input keyevent 82`, a secret menu should appears on your device.
2. Enable remote debugging
3. Restart the app
4. You should have a more detailed error.

(My problem was that the node module "Buffer" did not exists in my react-native application. I was able to remediate that.